# Building OpenGL SuperBible 7 for CentOS 7, missing glfw3

Tags: opengl, cmake, centos7, glfw

### The Problem

I'm working with CentOS 7 and have been trying to correct an issue with the build instructions, especially when trying to locate the glfw library. Following the instructions from the *HOWTOBUILD.txt* file (available from the SB7 git repo) I regularly received an error when running the `make` command:

```
[sweet_ass_user_name@bitchin_camaro build]$ make
Scanning dependencies of target sb7
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7color.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7ktx.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp.o
/usr/local/opengl/SDK_Sandbox/sb7code/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp: In member function ‘void sb7::object::render_sub_object(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
/usr/local/opengl/SDK_Sandbox/sb7code/src/sb7/sb7object.cpp:212:77: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                                             (void*)sub_object[object_index].first,
                                                                             ^
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7shader.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/sb7textoverlay.cpp.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sb7.dir/src/sb7/gl3w.c.o
[  5%] Linking CXX static library lib/libsb7.a
[  5%] Built target sb7
Scanning dependencies of target wrapmodes
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o
[  7%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/wrapmodes
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/wrapmodes] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To make things more confusing, I had already installed these packages:

- glfw
- glfw-devel

When checking my installed glfw packages, with `rpm -qa | grep glfw`, my system returns:

```
glfw-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64
glfw-devel-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64
```

So clearly, the installed glfw library is version 3 of the `glfw` library.

***Yet, why won't the system recognize it?***

---

### The Background and System Information

```
OS: centos-release-7-5.1804.4.el7.centos.x86_64
OpenGL: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 396.37
GPU: GV100
Optix: 5.1
CUDA: 9.2
CMake: cmake3, cmake3-gui
OpenGL libraries:
    mesa-libGLU-9.0.0-4.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libGLES-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libGLU-devel-9.0.0-4.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libwayland-egl-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libGL-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-filesystem-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libEGL-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-dri-drivers-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libglapi-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libxatracker-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libGL-devel-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
    mesa-libgbm-17.2.3-8.20171019.el7.x86_64
Graphics Misc Libs:
    libX11-common-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch
    libX11-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
    libX11-devel-1.6.5-1.el7.x86_64
    libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el7.x86_64
    libXinerama-devel-1.1.3-2.1.el7.x86_64
    glfw-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64
    glfw-devel-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64
```

---

### Links

- [OpenGL SuperBible v7 Code Repo](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code)
- [SB7 HOWTOBUILD.txt](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/HOWTOBUILD.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Answer

Turns out, because of a confusing naming issue regarding the difference between the **glfw package** and the **glfw version**, the answer was simply to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file (link here: [SB7 CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt))

Line 28 needed a single character removed. Change **glfw3** to **glfw**.

## BUT!!

Do not also be rename the **glfw3** name from the line above. I can only assume that this is referring to the version of glfw3, and not the name of the package.

---

Now, the code builds and all the builds run fine.

---

### Additional Notes

For the centos7 system, and in order to work with current build rules for CUDA, you'll need to run `cmake3 ..` (instead of `cmake`)

---

### Fixed Code

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (superbible7)

LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Second, for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )

find_package(OpenGL)

set (CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")

if(WIN32)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 optimized glfw3 debug glfw3_d ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
elseif (UNIX)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb7 glfw X11 Xrandr Xinerama Xi Xxf86vm Xcursor GL rt dl)
else()
set(COMMON_LIBS sb7)
endif()
```